How do we filter one metric using label of another in Promql
I've a few metrics and based on a label value on a query we should get the output using Joins.
Example of input metrics:
info1{a="1", b="2", c="3", d="4", e="5"}
info1{a="2", b="2", c="1", e="5"}
info2{b="2", d="4", addnlabel="XYZ"}

The example is very generic but in our case label addnlabel value is going to be dynamic.
Now, I'm looking for help to join above metrics on labels b and d and filter results based on value of addnlabel=XYZ. In result I'd like to get metric info1 only if the condition matches.
Expected output:
info1{a="1", b="2", c="3", d="4", e="5"}


Does this answer your question? Prometheus: filter query based on another metric

Query for your example will be info1 and on(b,d) info2{addnlabel="XYZ"}

Also, if you agree this is in fact a duplicate, please don't delete this question. I believe it might be beneficial as signpost.

The following PromQL query should return info1 series, which contain b and d labels matching the corresponding labels at  info2 metric, which contains the given addnlabel="XYZ" label:
info1 and on(b, d) info2{addnlabel="XYZ"}

This query works in the following way:

It selects all the time series with the info1 name at the chosen timestamp (the timestamp is passed either via time arg at /api/v1/query or via start, end and step args at /api/v1/query_range ).
It selects all the time series with the info2 name, which contain addnlabel="XYZ" label.
It leaves only those info1 series, which contain b and d label values identical to the corresponding label values at the selected info2 series. See docs about and operator and or modifier.

